# DelegateCommand Async Support Prism 4.1

Tags: silverlight, prism, arcgis

As I see error in my code when I did Binding with DelegateCommand. in its Method I called 1 asyc service which is calling arcgis server to find the City names on using Task Service.

I'm bothered about Prism 4.1 Support async? If not is there any work around?

```
 public  DelegateCommand SearchCitiesCommand;
    private PlaceFinderService placeFinderService;

    public GenericMapViewModel()
    {
        HelloMapMessage = "Generic Map Pow Pow !!";
        placeFinderService = new PlaceFinderService();
        SearchCitiesCommand = DelegateCommand. //new DelegateCommand(Search);
    }

    public virtual async Task Search()
    {
        List<Graphic> graphics=await placeFinderService.FindAsync(SearchText);
        SearchResults = graphics;
    }
```

ASYN service

```
public class PlaceFinderService
{
    TaskCompletionSource<List<Graphic>> tcs;
    public Task<List<Graphic>> FindAsync(String searchText)
    {
        FindParameters findParams = new FindParameters();
        findParams.LayerIds.AddRange(new int[] { 0 }); // cities layer
        findParams.SearchFields.AddRange(new string[] { "CITY_NAME" });
        findParams.SpatialReference = new SpatialReference(4326);
        findParams.SearchText = searchText;
        FindTask findTask = new FindTask("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StatesCitiesRivers_USA/MapServer");
        tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<List<Graphic>>();
        findTask.ExecuteCompleted += FindTaskExecuteCompleted;
        findTask.Failed += findTaskFailed;
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    private void findTaskFailed(object sender, TaskFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        tcs.TrySetResult(new List<Graphic>());
    }

    private void FindTaskExecuteCompleted(object sender, FindEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Graphic> graphics = new List<Graphic>();
        foreach (var result in e.FindResults)
        {
            graphics.Add(result.Feature);
        }
        tcs.TrySetResult(graphics);

    }
}
```

I see few http://prismwindowsruntime.codeplex.com/discussions/535816 but I think its Prism 5.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, no MVVM framework supports "async commands". IMO, this is because there are lots of different semantic possibilities.

I have an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx) that you may find helpful. It provides a few ideas (and example implementations) but at the end of the day you'll have to craft your own "AsyncCommand" because the exact semantics will depend on your application's needs.

Comment: I'm new to this domain. is there any sample code for implementing in silverlight 5, Prism 4.1 ,MVVM application?

Comment: CommandManager is not available in my Silverlight 5, Prism 4.1 Application? and I got  Error 5 Cannot find all types required by the 'async' modifier. Are you targeting the wrong framework version, or missing a reference to an assembly? D:\Projecttrial\Aminations\showHideOne\AsyncSupport\AsyncCommandBase.cs 53 9 showHideOne

Comment: On Silverlight, you need to install `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` for `async` support. I'm not sure of the proper `CommandManager` replacement for Silverlight (or if it actually needs one).